Riesz-Representation: Finite mass of compact sets in the complex case?
The Riesz-Markov Theorem gives for every positive linear functional $C_c(X)$ on a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$ a unique regular Borel measure $\mu$ s.t.
$\mu(K) < \infty$
for every compact $K$.
In the case complex of a complex linear functional, we obtain a complex measure instead. Is it in this case also true, that
$|\mu(K)|<\infty $ for every compact $K$ ?

If you write your complex measure as
$$ \mu = (\mu_{\text{real}}^+- \mu^-_{\text{real}}) + i (\mu_{\text{imag}}^+- \mu^-_{\text{imag}}), $$
where $ \mu_{\text{real}}^+, \mu_{\text{real}}^- , \mu_{\text{imag}}^+, \mu_{\text{imag}}^- $ are regular Borel measures.
Then the measure $\vert \mu \vert$ is just the positive measure $\mu_{\text{real}}^+ + \mu^-_{\text{real}} + \mu_{\text{imag}}^+ + \mu^-_{\text{imag}}$, which gives finite measure to compacts by the triangle inequality.

Allright, thank you!

@MacMenders You're welcome.
